# Its not there though, it's actually somewhere else

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

I've placed one letter for you.

**What's the answer I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

Hint 1

> What's the product of the green things (they're not apples or limes if that's what you thought) on the top? And what does the grid look like? (colors significant)

Comment: Ignore the white dots/stars inside the squares. Unintentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've just cracked this. The answer should be...

> **Étienne Gueffier's [Spanish Steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Steps)**.

My solution path was as follows:

> 1. The red and yellow stripes bear a similarity to the flag of Spain:
>
>  [image: Spanish flag]
>
>  2. We are, therefore, likely looking for something to do with Spain which satisfies the title in that it *sounds* Spanish but actually isn't. Calling on my pub quiz trivia immediately makes me think of the **Spanish Steps**, a landmark in *Rome, Italy* (not Spain).
>
>  3. The diagram has 12 white boxes ascending along the diagonal... looking a lot like *steps*, in fact. Moreover, if we enter the letters SPANISHSTEPS into these 12 boxes they not only fit exactly but the already-given 'H' falls into precisely the right box. This is confirmation we are on the right track.
>
>  4. But what is the image at the top about? Well, noting that 1x2x9 is *eighteen* I scanned the Spanish Steps Wikipedia page for references with relevance to the number '18' but turned up nothing. However, I then noticed that the Spanish Steps were built using funds from the French diplomat *Étienne Gueffier*, and 'Étienne' sounds a bit like 'eighteen'... So perhaps these fruits may be something that sounds like 'Gueffier'. This led me to conclude that what we are looking at here are *eighteen guavas*.
>
>  5. Putting this all together gives us **Étienne Gueffier's** ("eighteen guavas") **Spanish Steps**, and I believe we have our solution!

**EDIT:** (post-solve) It seems that my interpretation of the top part of the puzzle was not at all what the OP intended, but a pleasant unintended coincidence! The OP's intent was instead...

> ...that these green objects are actually *peas*, not guavas (something I had in fact been using as my working hypothesis for a long time, but couldn't make work).
>
>  If we interpret the numbered peas as suggesting 'p1', 'p2' and 'p9', where 'p' means *prime* and the number besides it (say, *n*) represents the *n<sup>th</sup>* prime number, then this gives us a multiplication of 2 x 3 x 23 (the second, third and ninth primes), which has a value of 138 - and this is *the number of steps in the Spanish Steps*. And not a guava in sight...!

Comment: Ah, yes, I had some idea about this but couldn't make sense of the first image, well done!

Comment: @hexomino Thanks :) That was exactly my problem too. For a long time I thought they were peas, then mangos... This option only struck me when trying to back-solve from the info I found on the Wiki page - I'm not sure I've ever even seen one of these fruits before!

Comment: Nice job! Your initial thought was right, they are indeed rot13(crnf) :) I was planning to say this in the second hint, but haven't thought about this puzzle for a while. Rot13(Fb lbh tbg crn1, crn2, crn9 be nf vagraqrq c1kc2kc9... Vg jnf whfg n erohf gb znxr fher lbh jrer ba gur evtug genpx. Vgf fbzrguvat nobhg gur cebqhpg bs gubfr snpgbef.

Comment: Rot13(cevzr1*cevzr2*cevzr9 rdhnyf 138 juvpu vf gur gbgny ahzore bs fgrcf)